# Is it possible to mix zones with DNSSEC enabled and disabled in BIND?

Tags: dns, bind, dnssec

I have a dozen domains configured in a set of zones in BIND and I need to add a new one with DNSSEC enabled. If I enable DNSSEC:

```
options {
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
};
```

Will it break the other domains? It looks like it won't, but I want to be sure.

Comment: I tested it here and yes, you can mix zones with and without DNSSEC and it will work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `DNSSEC` settings are per zone. Setting the options for one zone does not affect any others.